# by so much as speck of soil

Tags: phrasal-verbs

*Her coachwork now dazzled the eye, her walnut fittings glowed with polish, her engine was undefiled **by so much as speck of soil**.*

I would like ask if the word "by" belongs to the word "undefiled" and consits the phrasal verb. Or is it used due to to the passive voice? I find thus "by" unnecessary there. Would it not be sufficient just "her engine was undefiled so much as speck of soil"?

Comment: I think 'by' is used to add the agent of the engine being undefiled. 'So much as' has been used to emphasize that something 'as not bigger than a speck of soil' made the engine undefiled.

Comment: BTW by adding agent at the end, I'm implying that it's a passive structure.

Comment: I think you've dropped an article.  "...by so much as a speck of soil".

Answer (score 1):

**Defiled** is just like **stained**.

> <sup>no</sup> The tablecloth was stained red wine.<sup>†</sup>
>
> The tablecloth was stained by red wine.
>
> The tablecloth was stained with red wine.
>
> The car was not defiled by so much as a speck of dirt.
>
> The car was not defiled with so much as a speck of dirt.

Both prepositional phrases, **by...** and **with...**, refer to the agent or instrumentality.

<sup>†</sup>but we could say "was stained *red* where a glass of wine had spilled."